# Make back button clics / hash changes fire an event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've made a single-page web presentation that changes it's content based on user events like clics, previous viewed content, source refers...

During usability tests I've detected that some users tend to use the back button and that leads them to the previous page, which is not what they want. They want to go back to the previous content.

As we are in the final stages of the production the easiest for me would be to **create an event that fires with clics in the back button**. The second easiest way would be to **detect changes in the window.location.hash** and fire an event.

I don't know how to do either.

It is necessary that this feature works in IE8+ FF4 and it's not that important on older browsers, as long as it doesn't compromise other features already implemented.

The page uses jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Use this http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/ or http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/ this.

Comment: Thanks @Ariel. I'll test it today and comment to let you know the results.